# Windbg script - STL map, displaying limited output in command output

Tags: dictionary, scripting, stl, windbg

I've been using Windbg for some months now and finally decided to write a script. My intention is to walk around the nodes of a STL map and display the key / value pairs. I have got to the point where I am outputting what I find, but my simple question is whether I can parse that output to make it clearer to read as it is surrounded by lots of extraneous information when I dump the `_Myval.first._Bx` and `_Myval.second._Bx` via `??` - what I'd *like* is to just get the stuff out that I am interested in, if that's possible.

For example, instead of seeing this when I do:

`.printf "\nTREE MAP NODE: %p\n", @$t0
.printf "  KEY = "
?? @$t0->_Myval.first._Bx`

`TREE MAP NODE: 00000010bc1f2cb0
  KEY = union std::_String_val<char,std::allocator<char> >::_Bxty
   +0x000 _Buf             : [16]  "Connections"
   +0x000 _Ptr             : 0x00004c5353657355  "--- memory read error at address 0x00004c5353657355 ---"
   +0x000 _Alias           : [16]  "Connections"`

I'd like to see this:

`TREE MAP NODE: 00000010bc1f2cb0
  KEY = "Connections"`

So I could end up displaying like this:

`TREE MAP NODE: 00000010bc1f2cb0
  KEY = "Connections"
  VALUE = "10"
TREE MAP NODE: 00000010bc1f2cc0
  KEY = "StartupTask"
  VALUE = "TestTask"
TREE MAP NODE: 00000010bc1f2cd0
  KEY = "Location"
  VALUE = "UK"`

I know I can use `??` to look at a node's `_Myval.first` where the size of whatever is held in it is shown, e.g. `0xb` and I can even pull just that out with something like `_Myval.first._Mysize` returning `unsigned int64 0xb` but can I do the same with the *contents*?

This is probably my lack of experience, but if I try and show what's in `_Myval.first._Bx._Buf` then I just get an address and the first character returned, e.g. `'C'`... so, my questions amounts to this - as I know *where* the *thing* I want is held, and I know how *long* it is (if I need to know this) - then how can I display just that... rather than the whole `_Bx` which currently comes back with `_Buf`, `_Ptr` and `_Alias`?

Comment: I commented before that if I do a `??` on a node's `_Myval.first._Bx._Buf` I see an address and the first character. If I pass that address (using copy and paste) to `da` then I see the whole contents, not just the first character (including the address echoed back - but that would be an improvement). I think I'm now missing how to get *just* the address from `_Myval.first._Bx._Buf` passed to `da`.

Comment: Still hacking away (and that's what this is!) at this... `da @@c++(&@$t0->_Myval.first._Bx)` *seems* to get me a good-ish result if what I want to see is contained within `_Buf`, but if it's contained within `_Ptr` then no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shown below are few examples of playing with STL template display in windbg

Try the new dx expression evaluator it drills down to the last member and pretty prints it

One can use javascript also if you are using the latest windbg versions instead of windbgs native scripting

assuming one  has a private pdb for the code one is debugging

if done **dv** after the map was initialized on the function 
and if an iterator is available one can use it directly

```
0:000> ?? iter._Ptr->_Myval.second
char * 0x000341a0
 "Alpha"
```

if one  wants to printf in bold

```
.printf /D "contents of iter_.second is <b>%ma</b>\n" , @@c++(iter._Ptr->_Myval.second)
contents of iter_.second is Alpha
```

if one wants to enumerate each pair in the map one has to enumerate the parent left and right branches

```
0:000> ?? mymap._Mypair._Myval2._Myval2._Myhead->_Parent->_Myval
struct std::pair<char const ,char const *>
   +0x000 first            : -120 '' (eax)
   +0x004 second           : 0x000341a8  "Beta"
0:000> ?? mymap._Mypair._Myval2._Myval2._Myhead->_Left->_Myval
struct std::pair<char const ,char const *>
   +0x000 first            : -120 '' (eax)
   +0x004 second           : 0x000341a0  "Alpha"
0:000> ?? mymap._Mypair._Myval2._Myval2._Myhead->_Right->_Myval
struct std::pair<char const ,char const *>
   +0x000 first            : -120 '' (eax)
   +0x004 second           : 0x000341c0  "Epsilon"
```

if one needs to print the Right Branch (the last member in the map)

```
.printf "the last memeber in map is %ma\n" , @@c++(mymap._Mypair._Myval2._Myval2._Myhead->_Right->_Myval.second)
the last memeber in map is Epsilon
```

using the latest dx expression evaluator to pretty print almost everything

```
0:000> dx mymap
mymap                 : { size=0x5 } [Type: std::map<char,char const *,std::less<char>,std::allocator<std::pair<char const ,char const *> > >]
    [<Raw View>]     [Type: std::map<char,char const *,std::less<char>,std::allocator<std::pair<char const ,char const *> > >]
    [comparator]     : less [Type: std::_Compressed_pair<std::less<char>,std::_Compressed_pair<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::pair<char const ,char const *>,void *> >,std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<char const ,char const *> > >,1>,1>]
    [allocator]      : allocator [Type: std::_Compressed_pair<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::pair<char const ,char const *>,void *> >,std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<char const ,char const *> > >,1>]
    [0x0]            : 65 'A', "Alpha" [Type: std::pair<char const ,char const *>]
    [0x1]            : 66 'B', "Beta" [Type: std::pair<char const ,char const *>]
    [0x2]            : 67 'C', "Gamma" [Type: std::pair<char const ,char const *>]
    [0x3]            : 68 'D', "Delta" [Type: std::pair<char const ,char const *>]
    [0x4]            : 69 'E', "Epsilon" [Type: std::pair<char const ,char const *>]
```

using dx expression evaluator one can cast any address as map like this

```
dx @$myvar = ((stdmap!std::map<char,char const *,std::less<char>,std::allocator<std::pair<char const ,char const *> > > * ) 0x17fb90)
```

after the cast 
one can use it like this

```
0:000> .for (r $t0 = 0 ; @$t0 < 5 ; r $t0 = @$t0+1) { dx @$myvar[0][@$t0].second }
@$myvar[0][@$t0].second                  : 0x341a0 : "Alpha" [Type: char *]
@$myvar[0][@$t0].second                  : 0x341a8 : "Beta" [Type: char *]
@$myvar[0][@$t0].second                  : 0x341b0 : "Gamma" [Type: char *]
@$myvar[0][@$t0].second                  : 0x341b8 : "Delta" [Type: char *]
@$myvar[0][@$t0].second                  : 0x341c0 : "Epsilon" [Type: char *]
```

the _Bx etc belong to std::string and not to map

printing a std::string

```
0:000> .printf "%ma\n" , @@c++(test._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr)

Hello I am Me Are You Thou
```

the _Bx is a union use appropriate member

```
0:000> ?? test._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf
char [16] 0x0013f888
96 '`'
0:000> ?? test._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr
char * 0x001a9860
 ".Hello I am Me Are You Thou."
0:000> ?? test._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Alias
char [16] 0x0013f888
96 '
```

or cast it to proper type befor printing

```
0:000> ?? (char *)*(unsigned long *)test._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf
char * 0x001a9860
 ".Hello I am Me Are You Thou."
```

or here is printf variant properly casted for _Buf which holds a _Ptr

```
0:000> .printf "%ma\n" , @@c++( *(char **)(test._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf) )

Hello I am Me Are You Thou
```

if one wants to follow up
the code used to display these results is as follows

```
using namespace std;
#define ALLOCSIZ 5
const char *Greek_Alphabets[ALLOCSIZ] = { "Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta","Epsilon" };

__declspec(noinline) void  play_with_map() {
    cout << "playing with maps\n\n";
    map<char, const char*> mymap;
    for (int i = 0; i < ALLOCSIZ; i++) {
        mymap.insert(pair<char, const char*>('A' + i, Greek_Alphabets[i]));
    }
    map<char, const char*>::iterator iter = mymap.begin();
    for (iter; iter != mymap.end(); iter++)
        cout << iter->first << " = " << iter->second << "\n";
}
__declspec(noinline) void play_with_vector(){
    cout << "playing with vectors\n\n";
    vector< pair< char, const char* > > myvec;
    for (int i = 0; i < ALLOCSIZ; i++) {
        myvec.push_back(make_pair('A' + i, Greek_Alphabets[i]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ALLOCSIZ; i++) {
        cout << myvec[i].first << " = "<< myvec[i].second <<"\n";
    }
}
int main() {
    play_with_map();
    play_with_vector();
    return 0;
}
```

the std::string function is as follows

```
__declspec(noinline) void play_with_std_string() {
    string test("\nHello I am Me Are You Thou\n");
    cout << test.c_str();
}
```

## JAVASCRIPT

---

An Example Javascript to dump std::map   **map <char , const char * > mymap**

```
"use strict";

// make an alias so that it can be used like regular bang command !dumpmap address
function initializeScript() {
    return [new host.functionAlias(dump_std_map, "dumpmap")];
}

// a helper to log strings
function log(instr) {
    host.diagnostics.debugLog(instr + "\n")
}

//use dt /v /t std::map* to get a type description string and pass it 
// or use the default (applicable for this example only 
// std::map< int , int > will not pan for  std::map <bar , foo > 
function dump_std_map(input , typedesc) {
    var typeDescription;
    if(typedesc) {
        typeDescription = typedesc 
        }else {
            typeDescription = "(std::map<char,char const *,std::less<char>,std::allocator<std::pair<char const ,char const *> > > *)"
        }   
    var foo = host.evaluateExpression( typeDescription + input.toString() )
    var mapsize = foo._Mypair._Myval2._Myval2._Mysize
    for (var i=0; i<mapsize;i++) 
    {
        log (foo.dereference().Skip(i).First().toString())
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
0:000> ? mymap
Evaluate expression: 2357904 = 0023fa90
0:000> !dumpmap 0x23fa90
65 'A', "Alpha"
66 'B', "Beta"
67 'C', "Gamma"
68 'D', "Delta"
69 'E', "Epsilon"
@$dumpmap(0x23fa90)
```

Comment: Thanks for this input - it looks like this `.printf "%ma\n" , @@c++(test._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr)` was the most valuable thing I got from the response; it's really helpful and allows me to cleanly print out the contents of a `_Myval.first`. I found if the contents are short it displays perfectly using: `.printf " KEY = %ma\n", @@c++(&@$t0->_Myval.first)` or `.printf " KEY = %ma\n", @@c++(&@$t0->_Myval.first._Bx)` or `.printf " KEY = %ma\n", @@c++(&@$t0->_Myval.first._Bx._Ptr)`.

Comment: But if the contents are long, only shown in `_Ptr` when doing a `?? @$t0->_Myval.first._Bx`, `_Buf` showing `[16]  "???"`, for example - `RunningInBackground`, then I *only* see something like `2B` when doing the `.printf` (whether for `_Myval.first`, `_Myval.first._Bx` or `_Myval.first._Bx._Ptr`). It would be nice to understand that too. As I can only see what's in `_Ptr` if I do the whole `?? @$t0->_Myval.first._Bx` (it seems) and that prints out lots of extraneous stuff along with it.

Comment: My running of `?? @$t0->_Myval.first._Bx` will result in this, I would like to be able to see a neat "RunningInBackground":  `union std::_String_val<char,std::allocator<char> >::_Bxty
   +0x000 _Buf             : [16]  "???"
   +0x000 _Ptr             : 0x0000001342320410  "RunningInBackground"
   +0x000 _Alias           : [16]  "???"`

Comment: Thank you for the great pointers here - this is what I've come up with, which seems to produce nice results for me:     `.if (@@c++(@$t0->_Myval.first._Mysize)<10)
    {
      .printf "\n    KEY = %ma", @@c++(&@$t0->_Myval.first._Bx._Buf)
    }
    .else
    {
      .printf "\n    KEY = %ma", @@c++(*(char**)(@$t0->_Myval.first._Bx._Buf))
    }

    .if (@@c++(@$t0->_Myval.second._Mysize)<10)
    {
      .printf "\n  VALUE = %ma\n", @@c++(&@$t0->_Myval.second._Bx._Buf)
    }
    .else
    {
      .printf "\n  VALUE = %ma\n", @@c++(*(char**)(@$t0->_Myval.second._Bx._Buf))
    }`

Comment: It was this snippet that got me there - `.printf "%ma\n" , @@c++( *(char **)(test._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Buf) )`